# SuiteScript Script sending statements

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I couldn't find an answer to this in docs or here. Is it possible to script sending statements to customers? thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in SuiteAnswers, it is enough for my purposes.

```
function printStatement()
{
//this is is the customer id
var id = nlapiGetRecordId();
var email = nlapiGetFieldValue('custentity_accounting_email');            
//create an array to set the STATEMENT properties(optional)
var sdate = new Array();
sdate.startdate = '11/01/2015'; // replace it as per  requirement
sdate.statementdate = '11/30/2015'; // replace it as per  requirement
sdate.openonly = 'T'; // replace it as per  requirement
sdate.formnuber = 112; // replace it as per  requirement

//print the statement to a PDF file object
var file = nlapiPrintRecord('STATEMENT', id, 'PDF', sdate);

//send the PDF as an attachment
nlapiSendEmail('-5', email, 'Regular Statement', 'Please see attached     Statment', null, null, null, file); //change the value of  author id.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it's even easier to do it with a workflow.  We created a custom field for a 'Statement Contact' and set up a scheduled workflow based on a 'Saved Search Filter' which basically checks that the customer has a balance.  There is one state which contains a single 'Send Email' action.  The 'Send Email' action has the option to 'Include Statement'.  It fires on the 4th day of each month - you can set this or any other parameter to whatever suits you.  This works fine for us, so I hope it helps you.